# Update safe app list to include our dapp on the newly supported networks

Tags: safe-core, safe, safe-apps-sdk

Hi our app is in the safe app list for the original list of networks safe supports, is there a process to expand this to the new networks?

Our app already supports the new networks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an demand by filling this template asking to add new supported network by filling [this template](https://github.com/5afe/safe-apps-list/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=safe-app-request.md). Please be as precise as possible and follow each steps in the form.

Thanks! Louis